# $divide elements of Embedded Documents - MongoDB Aggregation

Tags: mongodb, aggregation

I am trying to create an aggregation MongoDB query.

Structure of data:

```
{
    "object_name": Example,
    "values": [ {"name":"value1", "value":1}, 
                {"name":"value2", "value":10},
                {"name":"total", "value":105}
}
```

Goal: Find *object names* where `value1/total > 0.5` and `value2/total > 0.25` and `total > 100`. 
The data is structured in this way to provide indexes on the value_name and value fields.

What I tried - aggregate with the following pipelines:

$match: filter documents with total > 100:

```
$match: { values: { $elemMatch: { value_name: "total", value: {$gte: 100 }
```

$project: grab only the value_names that we need (there are close to 200 different names)

```
$project: {
            values: {
                $filter: {
                    input: "$values",
                    as: "value",
                    cond: { $or: [
                        { $eq: [ "$$value.name", "name1"] },
                        { $eq: [ "$$value.name", "name2"] },
                        { $eq: [ "$$value.name", "total"] },
                    ] }
                }
            },
            name: 1
        }
```

then, `{ $unwind: "$values" }`

And here, I could `$group` to `$divide: name1/total, name2/total` however I'm stuck on how to get those values. 
I can't simply do `stats.value:` because it does not know which value I'm referring to. I believe `$group` can't do `$elemMatch` to also match the name.

If there are simpler solutions that this, I'd greatly appreciate your input.

Comment: So you wanted to have documents where all these three `value1/total > 0.5`, `value2/total > 0.25` & `total > 100` satisfied & also response contain only those objects in `values` array?

Comment: Yes, I want to have the three conditions satisfied. The only field I care about returning is the "object_name".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this :

1. We're filtering documents where values array has an object with
   `name : total` & `value > 100`.
2. Adding object with `name : total`
       to document.
3. Leaving only objects that match with criteria
   `value1/total > 0.5` and `value2/total > 0.25` in values array.
4. If
   size of that array is greater than `1`, then those two conditions are
   met.
5. Finally projecting only `object_name`

**Query :**

```
db.yourCollectionName.aggregate([{ $match: { values: { $elemMatch: { name: "total", value: { $gte: 100 } } } } }, 
    {
        $addFields: {
            totalValue: {
                $arrayElemAt: [{
                    $filter: {
                        input: "$values",
                        as: "item",
                        cond: { $eq: ["$$item.name", 'total'] }
                    }
                }, 0]
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            values: {
                $filter: {
                    input: "$values",
                    as: "value",
                    cond: {
                        $or: [
                            { $cond: [{ $eq: ["$$value.name", "value1"] }, { $gt: [{ $divide: ["$$value.value", '$totalValue.value'] }, 0.5] }, false] },
                            { $cond: [{ $eq: ["$$value.name", "value2"] }, { $gt: [{ $divide: ["$$value.value", '$totalValue.value'] }, 0.25] }, false] }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }, object_name: 1
        }
    }, {
        $match: {
            $expr: { $gt: [{ $size: "$values" }, 1] }
        }
    }, { $project: { object_name: 1, _id: 0 } }])
```

**Collection Data :**

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e20bd94d02e05b694d55fa5"),
    "object_name" : "Example",
    "values" : [ 
        {
            "name" : "value1",
            "value" : 1
        }, 
        {
            "name" : "value2",
            "value" : 10
        }, 
        {
            "name" : "total",
            "value" : 105
        }, 
        {
            "name" : "total1",
            "value" : 105
        }
    ]
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e20bdb1d02e05b694d56490"),
    "object_name" : "Example2",
    "values" : [ 
        {
            "name" : "value1",
            "value" : 1
        }, 
        {
            "name" : "value2",
            "value" : 10
        }, 
        {
            "name" : "total",
            "value" : 5
        }, 
        {
            "name" : "total1",
            "value" : 5
        }
    ]
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e20d1b7d02e05b694d7c57a"),
    "object_name" : "Example3",
    "values" : [ 
        {
            "name" : "value1",
            "value" : 100
        }, 
        {
            "name" : "value2",
            "value" : 100
        }, 
        {
            "name" : "total",
            "value" : 200
        }, 
        {
            "name" : "total1",
            "value" : 205
        }
    ]
}

/* 4 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e20d1cad02e05b694d7c71c"),
    "object_name" : "Example4",
    "values" : [ 
        {
            "name" : "value1",
            "value" : 200
        }, 
        {
            "name" : "value2",
            "value" : 40
        }, 
        {
            "name" : "total",
            "value" : 200
        }, 
        {
            "name" : "total1",
            "value" : 205
        }
    ]
}

/* 5 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e20d1e2d02e05b694d7c933"),
    "object_name" : "Example5",
    "values" : [ 
        {
            "name" : "value1",
            "value" : 150
        }, 
        {
            "name" : "value2",
            "value" : 100
        }, 
        {
            "name" : "total",
            "value" : 200
        }, 
        {
            "name" : "total1",
            "value" : 205
        }
    ]
}
```

**Result :**

```
/* 1 */
{
    "object_name" : "Example5"
}
```

Comment: This is a very clear solution. Thank you for the explanation!

Answer (score 1):

You may convert your array into object with [$arrayToObject](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayToObject/index.html) operator and add `tmp` field to have easy access to `value1`, `value2`, `total` values

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      tmp: {
        $arrayToObject: {
          $map: {
            input: "$values",
            as: "value",
            in: {
              k: "$$value.name",
              v: "$$value.value"
            }
          }
        }
      },
      name: 1
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      $expr: {
        $and: [
          {
            $gt: [
              {
                $divide: [
                  "$tmp.value1",
                  "$tmp.total"
                ]
              },
              0.5
            ]
          },
          {
            $gt: [
              {
                $divide: [
                  "$tmp.value2",
                  "$tmp.total"
                ]
              },
              0.25
            ]
          },
          {
            $gt: [
              "$tmp.total",
              100
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      tmp: 0
    }
  }
])
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/N24lnhSTBhM)

Comment: `$arrayToObject` together with `$map` were the key to this question :) Works well and even works without adding the temporary values. Thank you so much!

Comment: Yes, you are right, optimize your pipeline. You are welcome